# Resize inner div when the image is automatically resized?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make this image auto resize when the browser size changes which works fine, however the green box still stays the same width, How can i make that change relative to the outer div? Otherwise when the image gets to about half size, the green box takes up the majority of the image.

My HTML

```
<div class="hero-container">
    <img src="mri.png" class="main-bg" />
    <div class="box"><h3>Test Box Test Box Test Box </h3><p>This is a test box,This is a test box,This is a test box. </p></div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.hero-container {margin:0 auto;display:block;max-width:1400px;width:100%;position:relative;height:100%;max-height:710px;overflow:hidden}

.box {
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
   left: 40px;
   top: 30px;
   z-index: 1000;
   background-color: #92AD40;
   padding: 5px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-weight: bold;
   max-width:300px;
   max-height:300px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you were to make the parent div `position: relative;`, all positioning and sizing of the inner div would then be calculated with respect to the parent div. This would allow you to size and position it relative to the outer div, instead of relative to the entire window. You'd then have to set a *relative* width, like `width: 40%;`, instead of a hard-coded value like `300px`.

Comment: the `.hero-container` is already set to relative, is that the right one?

Comment: Yes, see my edit. I believe you want to assign a percentage-based `width` to `.box`.

Comment: Also `max-width:300px;` is in `px`, you should change `width` by `media query` or use `width` in `%`

Comment: @Santi How can i see your edit?

Comment: I meant that I had edited my original comment to include more information, notably about using relative widths.

Comment: Thanks, using the percentage worked great.